# How to use loop to get the word frequency of a list object and store in a dict object?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nlp

I have a list called `data` and a dict object called `word_count`, before converting the frequency into unique integers, I want to return a dict object `word_count` (expected format: `{'marjori': 1,'splendid':1...}`) and then sort the frequency.

```
data = [['marjori',
 'splendid'],
 ['rivet',
 'perform',
 'farrah',
 'fawcett']]

def build_dict(data, vocab_size = 5000):

    word_count = {}
    for w in data:
        word_count.append(data.count(w)) ????
    #print(word_count)

    # how can I sort the words to make sorted_words[0] is the most frequently appearing word and sorted_words[-1] is the least frequently appearing word.

    sorted_words = ??
```

I'm new to Python, can someone help me, thanks in advance. (I only want to use `numpy` library and for loop.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python collections.counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772092/python-collections-counter)

Comment: Hi @Sushanth I only want to use ```numpy``` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each word, you need to create a dict entry if it doesn't exist yet, or add 1 to it's value if it does exist:

```
 word_count = dict()
        for w in data:
            if word_count.get(w) is not None:
                word_count[w] += 1
            else:
                word_count[w] = 1
```

Then you can sort your dictionary by value:

```
word_count = {k: v for k, v in sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
```

Comment: Hi I got an error ```TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'```, I made a mistake in the data variable, I've updated it in the question, it looks like this ```[['aaa',bbb'], ['ccc', 'ddd']]```

Comment: The drawback of the way to sort dictionary by value is that I can't call it by using ```word_count[0]```, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Once your dictionary is sorted you can use `list(word_count.keys())[0]` to get the word with the highest count.

Comment: I'll have to modify the last bit of my function, I don't want to change it, is there a way to modify the ```sort``` functionality?

Comment: just replace `sorted_words` with `list(word_count.keys())`

Comment: Got you, than you soooo much!

Answer (score 1):

The last part of your code is not understandable, but if you only want to count the words and insert it into a dictionary and sort it by it frequency in descending order, I would suggest to use `defaultdict` and implement it like this:

```
data = ['marjori',
 'splendid',
 'rivet',
 'farrah',
 'perform',
 'farrah',
 'fawcett']
from collections import defaultdict

def build_dict(data, vocab_size = 5000):
    """Construct and return a dictionary mapping each of the most frequently appearing words to a unique integer."""

    word_count = defaultdict(int) # A dict storing the words that appear in the reviews along with how often they occur
    for w in data:
        word_count[w]+=1
    #print(word_count)

    # how can I sort the words to make sorted_words[0] is the most frequently appearing word and sorted_words[-1] is the least frequently appearing word.

    sorted_words = {k: v for k, v in sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}

    return sorted_words

build_dict(data)
```

Output:

```
{'farrah': 2,
 'fawcett': 1,
 'marjori': 1,
 'perform': 1,
 'rivet': 1,
 'splendid': 1}
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the data variable, I've updated it in the question, it looks like this ```[['aaa',bbb'], ['ccc', 'ddd']]```, and I only want to use ```numpy```, I'm thinking to add two loops but not sure how to do it.